# Creating a JSON object from loops and strings

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a JSON object with the following structure… I realize that the JSON object shouldn’t have comments but in this example I just want to explain the desired structure

```
selObj = {

    category: selectedCategory, // 1 category only

    catOptions:{
        optionValue:discountValue, // we can 1 or have many of paired keys in this sub object
        optionValue:discountValue,
        optionValue:discountValue
    },

    tariff:{
        tariffValue:discountValue, // we can 1 or have many of paired keys in this sub object
        tariffValue:discountValue
    },

    tarOptions:{
        tarOption:discountValue // we can 1 or have many of paired keys in this sub object

    }

};
```

Now I have a function that will populate the empty object that I declare at the start of my script like so…

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var selObj = {}; 
        populateMyEmptyObject(selObj)

});

populateMyEmptyObject(emptyObject){

        emptyObject.category = "Category"

        // in my original function I have loops that produce strings with the following structure {"value1":"10","value2":"20","value3":"30","value4":"40"}, for this example I’ll call them loopReturn1,  loopReturn2, loopReturn3, loopReturn4

        // loops have happened and vars are produced... I've removed my loops as they're working just fine, I've omitted that code for simplicity

        emptyObject.catOptions = loopReturn1;
        emptyObject.tariff = loopReturn2;
        emptyObject.tarOptions = loopReturn3;
}
```

Now with this I'm constantly getting errors with whitespace problems and so on. I've been told I should use `JSON.stringify`, which I have but I'm still getting problems. Now forgetting the loops, how should I take the produced string and append these to my object, can someone tell me the best practice to take the strings and convert/parse them to my original object called selObj. Also do I need to return my emptyObject in my function to update the selObj (like `return emptyObject;`)

Should I change my original empty object so it better represents my desired structure, like so:

```
var selObj = {

    "category": "selectedCategory",

    "catOptions":{
                },

    "tariff":{
              },

    "tarOptions":{
     }

};
```

Any advice would be appreciated, I think it's pretty obviously that I'm a self taught developer and I've got a few bad habits and holes in my knowledge!

Comment: Are those "smart quotes" around `Category` a copy/paste error, or does it look like that in your source as well?

Comment: Just a copy and paste error... I'll edit, good spot BTW

Comment: "errors with whitespace problems" ... that doesn't make a lot of sense. You should post **exactly** what your constructed JSON looks like, or else nobody will have any idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzjke/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var o = getCategoryData(),
        sJSON = JSON.stringify(o);

    console.log(o, sJSON);
});

var getCategoryData = function(o) {

    // example functions start
    var getCategory = function() {
        return "Category";
    },
    getCatOptions = function() {
        return {value1: 10, value2: 20, value3: 30, value4: 40};
    },
    getTariff = function() {
        return {value1: 10, value2: 20, value3: 30, value4: 40};
    },
    getTarOptions = function() {
        return {value1: 10, value2: 20, value3: 30, value4: 40};
    };
    // example functions end

    if (!o) o = {};
    o.category = getCategory();
    o.catOptions = getCatOptions();
    o.tariff = getTariff();
    o.tarOptions = getTarOptions();
    return o;
}​
```